# Merge [kafka] into [apache-kafka]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[apache-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) seems to be the legit tag, but confusingly [kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka) exists and seems to be less used.

When I added a question, I added both.

We should remove this confusion, [apache-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) seems to be more complete and more used, so we should make [kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka) a synonym of [apache-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka)?

Comment: I think we should call it as apache-kafka as there might be different questions around different platforms e.g. confluent kafka, cloudera kafka. So it would be better if we keep it apache-kafka to be very specific when we ask anything related